# Are there any PC games that utilize the Wii Remote's 3D functionality?

Tags: pc, linux, wiimote

Are there any PC games (windows or linux) that support the wiimote?  Specifically, games that don't just map the mouse, but use data from the gyroscope (like Wii Sports games: tennis, golf). I want to find games that could use most of the wiimote 3d functionality.

There are plenty of guides on how to connect a Wii Remote to PC, but not what games we could play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any games specifically made for PC, but the [Dolphin](http://dolphin-emu.com/) emulator can play some Wii games (and can use the Wiimote as a control if your computer has Bluetooth support).

Comment: It seems Dolphin is the only way. I tried it, and realized that 22" monitor is too small to play from 2 meters :)

Answer (score 3):

(**edit** please note this answer was posted before the question was refined to make my answer trivial...)

---

Since the wiimote will act as a mouse (with 11 keys that can also be mapped to keyboard keys)  *any* game that can be played via mouse (and not too many keys) can be played via wiimote as well. It can also be used as a gamepad replacement. So the answer is:

**All games that can be played via mouse and require no more than 8 keyboard keys** (I subtracted the three mouse keys)

Comment: Thank you for answer, it helped me to make my question more concrete. If you just use wiimote as mouse, then most of functionality is lost, and game dosn't much differ from original gameplay. I belive there should be games that is not possible to play with mouse and kb, but possible only with wiimote (or such kind of device).

Comment: @kusoksna Well, yes, there are. Those are Wii games. What would motivate someone to create a game that supports the Wiimote just for the few people that both have a Wii and have it enabled with their PC?